# Why won't Python Turtle respond to my movement inputs?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm taking a coding course this semester and for one of the projects it requires us to make a game of any kind. I chose to make a game contained within a box where enemies move on screen travel completely across then appear again at a different x or y coordinate to add some variety. The issue I'm dealing with is following adding the code needed to create "enemies" the keys I set for the movement of the player turtle no longer work, another strange thing is that the player turtle will spin in place right as the program is run. I am at a total loss as to how to make the turtle respond to the code as it worked correctly prior to writing the code for the enemies. I don't believe the code for the enemies is the issue as when it is commented out it still acts the same way. I didn't include the enemies code for the sake of brevity. this code is done in Python 3. Please help if you can!
EDIT: I removed the parenthesis following the window.onkeypress(mov_x,"x") and after adding the code back in for the enemies it won"t respond, it works without the code for the enemies but that kinda removes the point of the game. Thank you for the help!

```
import turtle
import random
#screen
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Final Project Game")
window.bgcolor("gray")
window.setup(width=600,height=600)
#player
t= turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(5)
t.shape("triangle")
t.color("blue")
t.penup()
#player movement

def mov_rt():
    t.seth(0)
    t.fd(20)
def mov_lt():
    t.seth(180)
    t.fd(20)
def mov_up():
    t.seth(90)
    t.fd(20)
def mov_dw():
    t.seth(270)
    t.fd(20)


window.onkeypress(mov_rt,"d")
window.onkeypress(mov_lt,"a")
window.onkeypress(mov_up,"w")
window.onkeypress(mov_dw,"s")
window.listen()

#enemies
enemies = []
turt_num = turtle.numinput("Final","Number of Enemies", default=5, minval=1,maxval=10)
e_dir= [0,90,180,270]
if turt_num == 1:
    e1= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e1.speed(5)
    e1.color("red")
    e1.penup()
    e1.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e1.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e1)
    e1.st()
elif turt_num == 2:
    e1= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e1.speed(5)
    e1.color("red")
    e1.penup()
    e1.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e1.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e1)
    e2= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e2.speed(5)
    e2.color("red")
    e2.penup()
    e2.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e2.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e2)
    e1.st()
    e2.st()
elif turt_num ==3:
    e1= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e1.speed(5)
    e1.color("red")
    e1.penup()
    e1.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e1.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e1)
    e2= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e2.speed(5)
    e2.color("red")
    e2.penup()
    e2.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e2.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e2)
    e3= turtle.Turtle("square",visible=False)
    e3.speed(5)
    e3.color("red")
    e3.penup()
    e3.setpos(random.randint(-290,290),random.randint(-290,290))
    e3.seth(random.choice(e_dir))
    enemies.append(e3)
    e1.st()
    e2.st()
    e3.st()

#borders
def border(): #if you hold down the button it wont reappear bc youre still moving while the turtle is trying to move to the desired target
    tx, ty= t.pos()
    if t.xcor() >295:
        t.ht()
        t.setpos(-295,ty)
        t.st()
    if t.xcor() <-295:
        t.ht()
        t.setpos(295,ty)
        t.st()
    if t.ycor() >295:
        t.ht()
        t.setpos(tx,-295)
        t.st()
    if t.ycor() <-295:
        t.ht()
        t.setpos(tx,295)
        t.st()



#main game loop
while True:
    window.update()
    border()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm quite rusty  with turtle, but that loop at the bottom is suspicious. The `while True` loop will never exit, so `turtle.mainloop()` will never run.

Comment: `window.onkeypress(mov_rt(),"d")` calls the `mov_rt` function exactly once, right that that moment at time, then assigns its return value (which is `None`) as the handler for later presses of the "d" key.  You want to pass *the function itself* (so just `mov_rt` with no parentheses) as the parameter here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
window.onkey()
```

That is a different way to listen and it does the exact same thing.
Also, remember at the end of that code you need

```
window.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Common beginner's error.  Instead of:

```
window.onkeypress(mov_rt(),"d")
window.onkeypress(mov_lt(),"a")
window.onkeypress(mov_up(),"w")
window.onkeypress(mov_dw(),"s")
```

Do:

```
window.onkeypress(mov_rt, "d")
window.onkeypress(mov_lt, "a")
window.onkeypress(mov_up, "w")
window.onkeypress(mov_dw, "s")
```

That is, you don't want to *call* your event handler function, you instead want to *pass* the name of your event hanlder function for the system to call later, when something actually happens.

Below is a rework of your code to address this as well as some other turtle and Python issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def border():
    x, y = turtle.position()

    if x > 295:
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.setx(-295)
        turtle.showturtle()
    elif x < -295:
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.setx(295)
        turtle.showturtle()

    if y > 295:
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.sety(-295)
        turtle.showturtle()
    elif y < -295:
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.sety(295)
        turtle.showturtle()

# player movement
def mov_rt():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(20)
    border()

def mov_lt():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(20)
    border()

def mov_up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    border()

def mov_dw():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(20)
    border()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Final Project Game")
screen.bgcolor('gray')
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)

# player
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('normal')
turtle.shape('triangle')
turtle.color('blue')
turtle.penup()

screen.onkeypress(mov_rt, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(mov_lt, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(mov_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(mov_dw, 's')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Note removal of `while True:` loop as it has no place in an event-driven environment like turtle -- it potentially blocks events from being processed.

Comment: Just to clarify on the start bit, they did not have the brackets in the `screen.onkeypress()` bit. Did they before your answer?

Comment: @PythonProgrammer, yes I believe they edited their code about 10 minutes after my answer and jasonharper's comment which appeared around the same time.